# How to dynamically sort by date in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a to do list app on flutter and I will like to sort the uploaded tasks by date(new ones appear first). for doing this I think a key should be givin to each of the uploaded items in the to do list and this key should include a Date. In react native for doing this I added a function to the data in a flatlist which sorted by date but since I am new to flutter I dont know how can that be done. Any Idea helps :)

main.dart

```
  List<String> _toDoItems = []; //this is the array in which the uploaded tasks are stored, btw Im not using any database.
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  void _addToDoItem(String task) {
    if(task.length > 0) {
      setState(() {  
        _toDoItems.add(task);
      });
    }
  }

  void _removeTodoItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _toDoItems.removeAt(index));
  }

  Widget _buildToDoItem(String toDoText, int index) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: Container(
        height: 58,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22.0, bottom: 12,),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1.5, color: Colors.red),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children:[
            Expanded(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  toDoText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                onTap: () => _removeTodoItem(index),
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Delete', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.5),),
              onPressed: () => _removeTodoItem(index),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildToDoList() {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < _toDoItems.length) {
            return _buildToDoItem(_toDoItems[index], index);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            title: Text('To Do List', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),
          )
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 60,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 10,
                      child: Container(
                        height: double.infinity,
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _controller,
                          autofocus: true,
                          onSubmitted: (val) {
                            _addToDoItem(val);
                            _controller.clear();
                          },
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,),
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 4,    
                      child: Container(
                        height: double.infinity,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text('ADD', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                          
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _addToDoItem(_controller.text);
                            _controller.clear();
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                          },
                        ),
                      ),                                          
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ), 
              _buildToDoList()
            ]
          ), 
                 
        ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `sort()` method of List, also you need to be able to stock in a way or another the time of creation of your task.

I've made an example with the code you've posted. Using it your last created element will always be the first of the list.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ToDoElement {
  final String task;
  final DateTime timeOfCreation;

  ToDoElement(this.task, this.timeOfCreation);
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  List<ToDoElement> _toDoItems = [];

  void _removeTodoItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _toDoItems.removeAt(index));
  }

  void _addToDoItem(String task) {
    if (task.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() => _toDoItems.add(ToDoElement(task, DateTime.now())));
    }
  }

  Widget _buildToDoItem(String toDoText, int index) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: Container(
        height: 58,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22, right: 22, bottom: 12),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1.5, color: Colors.red),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  toDoText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                onTap: () => _removeTodoItem(index),
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text(
                'Delete',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.5),
              ),
              onPressed: () => _removeTodoItem(index),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  int compareElement(ToDoElement a, ToDoElement b) =>
      a.timeOfCreation.isAfter(b.timeOfCreation) ? -1 : 1;

  Widget _buildToDoList() {
    _toDoItems.sort(compareElement);
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _toDoItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return _buildToDoItem(_toDoItems[index].task, index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
            child: AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              title: Text(
                'To Do List',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            )),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Container(
            height: 60,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(22),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 10,
                  child: Container(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _controller,
                      autofocus: true,
                      onSubmitted: (val) {
                        _addToDoItem(val);
                        _controller.clear();
                      },
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: Container(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text('ADD', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _addToDoItem(_controller.text);
                        _controller.clear();
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          _buildToDoList()
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code worked!! Can you please explain why did you added the ToDoElement class?

Comment: This is what I was talking about when I said that you a need a way to save the date of creation of your todoItem. The `ToDoElement` class have 2 properties: `task` which work the same way as what you have done before and `timeOfCreation` is here to keep track of when you've added the item.

Comment: mmmm ok I get it, One last question, how would you create a function that edits an item from the list?

Comment: Well you can either remove the `final` from the fields to be able to edit them or you can replace the entire element at the corresponding index.